# Scanning projects for liberty configuration changes

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have installed websphere liberty in my eclipse jee (oxygen) release on windows 7.  Since I installed it I see a "Scanning projects for liberty configuration changes"  background job that starts sometimes and shows up under the "Progress" tab. This background job blocks any everything until it completes. I am not able to compile. build, or run when this is happening. Is there anyway to disable this in eclipse ?